# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() but is using len()

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to make a program that always returns True for every item in a given list. However, if an element is the word 'flick', switch to always returning the opposite boolean value.
Notes:
"flick" will always be given in lowercase.
A list may contain multiple flicks.
Switch the boolean value on the same element as the flick itself.

I tried:

```
def flick_switch(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        global flick_count
        flick_count = 0
        flicker=[]
        if flick_count % 2 == 0:
            if flick_switch(i) != flick:
                flicker.append("True")
            else:
                flicker.append("False")
                flick_count = flick_count+1
        else:
            if flick_switch(i) != flick:
                flicker.append("False")
            else:
                flicker.append("True")
                flick_count = flick_count+1
    return flicker
```

And for example:codewars,flick,code, wars] should get me  True, False, False, False

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you expect `flick_switch(i)` to mean?

Comment: There are other bugs in your code too.  I recommend that you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

```py
l = []
b = True
for x in ['codewars','flick','code', 'wars']:
    l.append(b if x != 'flick' else (b := not b))
```

Alternately, use a *list-comprehension*.

```py
b = True
l = [b if x != 'flick' else (b := not b) for x in ['codewars','flick','code', 'wars']]
```